# Display the date in the address bar of the django application

Tags: python, django, date, url, view

I have an app in django 1.8. I want to have the ability, right after entering the page, to see filter results for a particular date, for example:

```
archive/2011/12
```

For the moment I have filtering results for example for `archive/2011/12` but it is after manually entering the date in the address bar, how to do it automatically when you click on the link and go to this view.
I will be grateful for any hint.

```
class ArchiveListView(ListView, FormView, MonthArchiveView):
    model = models.Booking
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.order_by('-date_start')
    min_year = queryset.aggregate(Min('date_start'))
    max_year = queryset.aggregate(Max('date_start'))
    paginate_by = 80
    template_name = 'events/archive_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
    date_field = 'date_start'
    allow_future = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        min_year = self.queryset.aggregate(Min('date_start'))
        max_year = self.queryset.aggregate(Max('date_start'))
        context = super(ArchiveListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mode'] = 'archive'
        context['year'] = range(min_year['date_start__min'].year, max_year['date_start__max'].year + 1)
        context['months'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', ]
        context['selected_year'] = self.kwargs['year']
        context['selected_month'] = self.kwargs['month']
        context['object_list'] = models.Booking.objects.filter(date_start__year=self.get_year(),
                                                               date_start__month=self.get_month())
        print(context['selected_year'])
        return context
```

My url:

```
url(r'^/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)$', views.ArchiveListView.as_view(), name="archives"),
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate all the different date permutations so that you can render them as links that the user can click?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I ask how to get automatically the year and month in the address (for example, where events occur). At this point I have entered the year and month in the link (I know this is not a good solution):
`<a href="{% url'archive:archives' year='2009' month='1' %}" title="{% trans'Archive' %}">`